# Heap Dijkstra Implementation is slower than Naive Dijsktra Implementation

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, dijkstra, min-heap

I have tried to implement the Naive and Heap Dijkstra as shown below but somehow my naive Dijkstra implementation is surprisingly faster. I debugged my code but couldn't understand where my problem in my implementations are.

Why is my heap-based implementation is slower than the naive implementation?

Raw data is stored here:
https://www.algorithmsilluminated.org/datasets/problem9.8.txt

Data Import and Manipulation:

```
import time
with open("DijkstraTest2.txt", 'r') as input:
    lines = input.readlines()

lengths = {}
vertices = []
for line in lines:
    contents = line.split("\t")
    vertices.append(contents[0])
    for content in contents:
        content = content.replace('\n', '')
        if ',' in content:
            edge = contents[0] + '-' + content.split(',')[0]
            lengths[edge] = int(content.split(',')[1])
```

Naive Dijkstra:

```
def NaiveDijkstra(vertices, start_point, lengths):
    X = [start_point]
    shortest_paths = {}
    for vertex in vertices:
        if vertex == start_point:
            shortest_paths[vertex] = 0
        else:
            shortest_paths[vertex] = 999999999999
    subset = [key for key in lengths.keys() if start_point == key.split('-')[0]
              and key.split('-')[0] in X and key.split('-')[1] not in X]
    while len(subset) > 0:
        temp_min_dict = {}
        for edge in subset:
            temp_min = shortest_paths[edge.split('-')[0]] + lengths[edge]
            temp_min_dict[edge] = temp_min
        new_edge = min(temp_min_dict, key=temp_min_dict.get)
        X.append(new_edge.split('-')[1])
        shortest_paths[new_edge.split('-')[1]] = shortest_paths[new_edge.split('-')[0]] + lengths[new_edge]
        subset = []
        for key in lengths.keys():
            if key.split('-')[0] in X and key.split('-')[1] not in X:
                subset.append(key)
    return shortest_paths

start_time = time.time()
print(NaiveDijkstra(vertices = vertices, start_point = '1', lengths = lengths)['197'])
print(time.time() - start_time, "seconds")
```

My Heap based Dijkstra code:

```
class Heap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 0
        self.lst = []

    def swap(self, a):
        if self.size == 1:
            return self.lst
        else:
            if a == 1:
                i = 1
            else:
                i = a // 2
            while i > 0:
                if i * 2 - 1 >= self.size:
                    break
                elif self.lst[i - 1][1] > self.lst[i * 2 - 1][1]:
                    temp = self.lst[i - 1]
                    self.lst[i - 1] = self.lst[i * 2 - 1]
                    self.lst[i * 2 - 1] = temp
                elif i * 2 >= self.size:
                    break
                elif self.lst[i - 1][1] > self.lst[i * 2][1]:
                    temp = self.lst[i - 1]
                    self.lst[i - 1] = self.lst[i * 2]
                    self.lst[i * 2] = temp
                i -= 1
        # print(f"output: {self.lst}")

    def insert(self, element):
        # print(f"input: {self.lst}")
        self.lst.append(element)
        self.size += 1
        self.swap(self.size)

    def extractmin(self):
        val = self.lst.pop(0)[0]
        self.size -= 1
        self.swap(self.size - 1)
        return val

    def delete(self, deleted):
        ix = self.lst.index(deleted)
        temp = self.lst[-1]
        self.lst[ix] = temp
        self.lst[-1] = deleted
        self.lst.pop(-1)
        self.size -= 1
        #self.swap(self.size)


def FastDijkstra(vertices, start_point, lengths):
    X = []
    h = Heap()
    width = {}
    shortest_paths = {}
    for vertex in vertices:
        if vertex == start_point:
            width[vertex] = 0
            h.insert((vertex, width[vertex]))
        else:
            width[vertex] = 999999999999
            h.insert((vertex, width[vertex]))
    while h.size > 0:
        w = h.extractmin()
        X.append(w)
        shortest_paths[w] = width[w]
        Y = set(vertices).difference(X)
        for x in X:
            for y in Y:
                key = f"{x}-{y}"
                if lengths.get(key) is not None:
                    h.delete((y, width[y]))
                    if width[y] > shortest_paths[x] + lengths[key]:
                        width[y] = shortest_paths[x] + lengths[key]
                    h.insert((y, width[y]))
    return shortest_paths


start_time = time.time()
print(FastDijkstra(vertices=vertices, start_point='1', lengths=lengths)['197'])
print(time.time() - start_time, "seconds")
```

Comment: What were the times? And how many nodes/edges are there?

Comment: 2.896439790725708 seconds for so-called fast Dijkstra and 1.7552669048309326 seconds for naive Dijkstra, this graph has 200 vertices and 3734 edges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you implemented the heap version is not efficient. Notably the following make it inefficient:

- All nodes are put on the heap instead of only the direct neighbors of the visited nodes. This makes the heap large and slower than needed.
- `Y = set(vertices).difference(X)` is a slow operation, and makes Y unnecessary large.
- The nested loop that tries every pair in the Cartesian product of X and Y to see if it is an edge. This point together with the previous should be replaced with a collection of edges starting from X, and then discarding edges that lead to already visited nodes.
- For every found edge to delete the target node from the heap, and re-insert it, even if the width didn't change! Deletion is a costly operation (see next point). Only if the Heap implementation supports a decrease-key operation, this is an option, but otherwise the heap should just get an extra entry for the same vertex, knowing that the one with the lowest cost will come out of the heap first.
- The heap's `delete` method has a bad time complexity due to the `.index()` call.
- The heap's `extractmin` method has a bad time complexity, due to the `.pop(0)` call. This has O(n) time complexity.
- The heap's `extractmin` does not give correct results (again due to that `pop(0)`). Here is a little script that shows a mistake:

  ```
  h = Heap()
  for value in 4, 3, 5, 2, 1:
      h.insert((value, value))
  print(h.extractmin())  # 1 = OK
  print(h.extractmin())  # 2 = OK
  print(h.extractmin())  # 4 = NOK. 3 expected.
  ```
- The data structure `lengths` does not allow to quickly find the edges from a particular vertex. But this is a point that is also making the naive implementation slow. I would however suggest to turn that in a dict.

If this is done right it should run faster. Certainly when you would make use of the native `heapq` module you'll get good running times.

Here is a (much) faster implementation. It doesn't bother about unreachable vertices, and doesn't bother about possibly having multiple entries on the heap for the same node (with different distances). But it does start with only the starting node on the heap, and uses `heapq`:

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop
from collections import defaultdict

def FastDijkstra(vertices, start_point, lengths):
    # Create a dictionary for the edges, keyed by source node
    edges = defaultdict(list)
    for key, length in lengths.items():
        x, y = key.split("-")
        edges[x].append((length, y))

    heap = [(0, start_point)]
    shortest_paths = {}
    while heap:
        cost, x = heappop(heap)
        if x in shortest_paths:
            continue  # this vertex had already been on the heap before
        shortest_paths[x] = cost
        for length, y in edges[x]:
            if y not in shortest_paths:
                heappush(heap, (cost + length, y))
    return shortest_paths
```

In my tests this ran hundreds times faster.

Comment: This is really helpful @trincot! Thank you very much, I noticed that I don't really need that nested for loop but only w as the head of the edge. Abolishing the first for loop on X made my implementation running in 0.07 seconds which a tremendous improvement. Also fixed my error in minextract,, however without delete method my implementation doesn't result the correct output, that's why I kept it. Will post the improved version in the answers.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to the above answer (wonderful analysis) I adjusted my implementation which is way faster than the previous version. It is shown below.

```
class Heap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 0
        self.lst = []

    def swap(self, a):
        if self.size == 1:
            return self.lst
        else:
            if a == 1:
                i = 1
            else:
                i = a // 2
            while i > 0:
                if i * 2 - 1 >= self.size:
                    break
                elif self.lst[i - 1][1] > self.lst[i * 2 - 1][1]:
                    temp = self.lst[i - 1]
                    self.lst[i - 1] = self.lst[i * 2 - 1]
                    self.lst[i * 2 - 1] = temp
                elif i * 2 >= self.size:
                    break
                elif self.lst[i - 1][1] > self.lst[i * 2][1]:
                    temp = self.lst[i - 1]
                    self.lst[i - 1] = self.lst[i * 2]
                    self.lst[i * 2] = temp
                elif self.lst[2*i - 1][1] > self.lst[i * 2][1]:
                    temp = self.lst[2*i - 1]
                    self.lst[2*i - 1] = self.lst[i * 2]
                    self.lst[i * 2] = temp
                i -= 1
        #print(f"output: {self.lst}")

    def insert(self, element):
        #print(f"input: {self.lst}")
        self.lst.append(element)
        self.size += 1
        self.swap(self.size)

    def extractmin(self):
        val = self.lst[0][0]
        del self.lst[0]
        self.size -= 1
        self.swap(self.size-1)
        return val

    def delete(self, deleted):
        ix = self.lst.index(deleted)
        temp = self.lst[-1]
        self.lst[ix] = temp
        self.lst[-1] = deleted
        del self.lst[-1]
        self.size -= 1
        #self.swap(self.size)


def FastDijkstra(vertices, start_point, lengths):
    X = []
    h = Heap()
    width = {}
    shortest_paths = {}
    for vertex in vertices:
        if vertex == start_point:
            width[vertex] = 0
            h.insert((vertex, width[vertex]))
        else:
            width[vertex] = 999999999999
            h.insert((vertex, width[vertex]))
    while h.size > 0:
        w = h.extractmin()
        X.append(w)
        shortest_paths[w] = width[w]
        Y = set(vertices).difference(X)
        for y in Y:
            key = f"{w}-{y}"
            if lengths.get(key) is not None:
                h.delete((y, width[y]))
                if width[y] > shortest_paths[w] + lengths[key]:
                    width[y] = shortest_paths[w] + lengths[key]
                h.insert((y, width[y]))
    return shortest_paths


start_time = time.time()
print(FastDijkstra(vertices=vertices, start_point='1', lengths=lengths)['197'])
print(time.time() - start_time, "seconds")
```

Comment: The `extractmin` implementation is wrong. For instance, insert values 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, and then extract twice. Second extraction gives 3 instead of 2.

Comment: Changed the insert and min extract, I tested your case with different ordering, looks ok now. Thanks!

Comment: The `extractmin` implementation is still wrong. For instance, insert key-values 3, 4, 7, 2, 6, 5, 1, and then extract twice. Second extraction gives 3 instead of 2.

Comment: I updated again the extractmin, it works all the test samples you have shown so far, checked it for some additional series. However if it still fails, it fails. I won't work further on this. Thank you again for the help and challenge!

Comment: I understand. There are still several problems... After every manipulation the heap should be valid (none of the parents should be greater than either of their children). By `del` this property is not guaranteed anymore and you often get an invalid heap. Also the `delete` method is not correct and can break the heap property. Try not to reinvent the wheel but look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_operations) where the algorithms are correctly explained with pseudo code.

Comment: Just an example of failing: insert 4, 5, 1, 3, 2 in that order, then extract the minimum (i.e. 1), then insert that 1 again, then extract the minimum again, and it is not 1, but 2. As long as your mechanics involve shifting the values in a list in linear fashion, it cannot work correctly, and that is what `del` does (shifting). It breaks the previous parent-child relationships throughout the tree.